# How to use the Qt eventFilter?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to detect when the `TabBar` button of a a tab widget, is being hovered and change her icon size.

I tried using stylesheet but it ain't working:

```css
QTabBar::tab:hover {
    icon-size: 64px;
}
```

The another option is to use `eventFilter`, trying to figure out what i'm doing wrong as the function is not being called:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->installEventFilter(ui->tabWidget->tabbar());
}


bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    // In your reimplementation of this function, if you want to filter
    // the event out, i.e. stop it being handled further, return true;
    // otherwise return false.

    if (event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter) {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        qDebug() << "Ate key press" << keyEvent->key();
    }

    // pass the event on to the parent class
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're try to do but your call to `installEventFilter` should probably be `ui->tabWidget->tabBar()->installEventFilter(this);` .

Comment: @G.M. and how do i access the tabBar obj? `*obj` only contains `"qt_tabwidget_tabbar"`

Comment: Just cast obj to QTabBar: `QTabBar* tbar = qobject_cast<QTabBar*>(obj)`.

Comment: @Daniel I guess what you want is  'if(obj==ui->tabWidget->tabBar())&&(event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter)';